# JSF custom message for validation error

Tags: validation, jsf, glassfish-3

I'm using GlassFish 3.1.2.2 and I want to define a generic validation message template to **not include** field identifier/label.

I've found couple of related topics on StackOverflow but none of these solutions (all involving *javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE*) is working.

1) placing ValidationMessages.properties in root of classpath (in my case it was placed in WEB-INF/classes of my WAR file) - no effect

2) defining the ValidationMessages.properties file in <message-bundle> in faces-config.xml - no effect

3) defining the ValidationMessages.properties file in <resource-bundle> in faces-config.xml - no effect

I tested that resource bundle is correctly working as I can use it in EL, example: #{text['javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE']} where *text* is my var from resource-bundle definition.

NOTE: I don't want to give validatorMessage attribute on each of input fields in my application. I just want to setup my custom message once for whole application.

IMPORTANT: the solution presented here [Mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/) is not working as well.

**NOTE:** I'm declaring to use JSF 2.0 and Glassfish 3.1.2.2 certainly supports that.
**NOTE:** I don't want to implement validation in managed bean instead of using JSF validation/Bean Validation.

Comment: You are using jsf 1.X, aren't you?

Comment: Mkyong solution works for me out of the box (with the zip provided) on glassfish 3.1.2.2

Comment: @gpilotino I just downloaded Mkyong sample again. When you don't enter any data and click "Submit" then following error messages appear:

1) _Username: Validation Error: Value is required._
2) _Date of Birth: Validation Error: Value is required._

I want these messages to be custom, for example "xyz". **I added _javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE=xyz_ line to MyMessages.properties and nothing changed**

Comment: I'm answering myself: to set custom message for required validation you need to set in **message-bundle**

1) **javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED_detail** - a message that is by default presented in h:message or h:messages tags - or when showDetail=true (it is by default)

2) **javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED** - a message that is presented when showSummary=true in h:message and h:messages tags

**NOTE:** this is not true that *javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE* is responsible for required-field-error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering myself: to set custom message for required-field validation you need to set following properties in messages bundle file (message bundle is defined in faces-config.xml by <message-bundle> tag):

1) **javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED_detail** - a message that is by default presented in h:message or h:messages tags - or when showDetail=true (it is by default). GENERALLY IT'S ENOUGH.

2) **javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED** - a message that is presented when showSummary=true in h:message and h:messages tags. Set this additionally if you display summary in your h:message/h:messages.

**NOTE:** this is not true that *javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE* is responsible for required-field-error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<h:messages>` in your jsp/xhtml
and to display error message from Managed Bean depending upon condition
Use

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
FacesMessage msg =new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, errorMessage,detailMessage);
ctx.addMessage(null, msg);
```

Comment: This is not what I asked. Of course I use h:message tags and I have no problems seeing validation messages.

Comment: Moreover I don't want to implement validation myself and create FacesMessage objects in my managed bean.